# did it possible to add modernizr to jsFiddle and view the css3 perspective in Chrome/firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css

I have ***Chrome***  **"version 20.0.1132.57 m"** and ***firefox***  **"version 14.0.1"** in

both browsers I don't see the effect of css3 perspective .

for couple day I try to realize what is the perspective properties.
but if I don't have ability to view it how can I know.
today I install safari and I able to see what is perspective.

did it possible to use with adding link as `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js`

to jsFiddle and to enjoy from the effect of perspective ?

if yes how can I do that thx?

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/tvXgG/5/)

many Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately No, `Modernizr` only detects what features are supported by the browser and does not extend it's functionality.

> Modernizr is a small JavaScript library that detects the availability of native implementations for next-generation web technologies, i.e. features that stem from the HTML5 and CSS3 specifications.

Comment: ok is there other option to implement that ? and what they mean when they write  modernizr add css classes ?

Comment: the only option that I'm aware of is using browser prefixes `-webkit-perspective: 300;  /* Saf4+, Chrome 12+ 
     -moz-perspective: 300;  /* FF10+ 
      -ms-perspective: 300;  /* IE10+ 
          perspective: 300;`